# Como fazer Streaming de videos com PHP ocultando URL do vídeo

Tags: php, url, vídeo, hospedagem, streaming

Estou montando meu site, quero por vídeos nele, mais o site fica na hospedagem e os videos em um servidor VPS.

Também não quero que os usuários saibam o link de origem dos vídeos(fique oculto) e nem tenham acesso a baixa-los.

A linguagem que procuro é em PHP.

Preciso de ajuda já procurei bastante e nada ajudou.

Comment: Não tem como. Se o browser acessa, o usuário acessa. E para a parte do streaming de vídeo propriamente dito tem que usar algo mais sério que PHP (a não ser que seja um servidorzinho pra meia duzia de pessoas acessar).

Comment: De qualquer maneira terá que existir um link, caso deseja que o usuário acesse via navegador, obviamente. O HTML5 suporta o `EME` (Encrypted Media Extensions), mas não sei muitas informações, ele é usado pelo Netflix por exemplo para dificultar a pirataria.

Comment: Poderia passar algum link de script que eu possa usar como base para estudo.
Tem como camuflar, como os sites porno fazem, entende.

Comment: Tem como exigir autenticação, definir permissões, tornar o link para o vídeo dinâmico usando um *hash*, etc. Mas "ocultar o link" **não dá**.

Comment: Preciso de algo igual os cursos online usam. Onde se passa o vídeo mais não tem como se baixar o vídeo. Já procurei muito mais nada.